# jQuery on checkout page for change of shipping method - hide show div 50% works

Tags: woocommerce

Adding some jQuery to the WooCommerce checkout page that will hide/show a div based on shipping method (local pickup).

This works initially but due to WooCommerce's ajax loader when switching shipping method the hidden div fades back in when the change has occurred.

I am not sure how to trigger the code again once the switch has happened.

```
jQuery('form.checkout').on('change','select[name^="shipping_method"]',function() {
    var val = jQuery( this ).val();
    if (val.match("^local_pickup")) {
                jQuery('.flexible-checkout-fields-review_order_before_submit').fadeIn();
        } else {
                jQuery('.flexible-checkout-fields-review_order_before_submit').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I expect the div (.flexible-checkout-fields-review_order_before_submit) to only be visible when local pickup is selected, else hide.

Like I say, it works initially, but when you switch the shipping method we are back to square one.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be in your first line where you have **select[name** instead of **input[name**

Here's some code I use for the same thing so should work for you if you change the name of the element you wish to hide.

I also check and uncheck the ship-to-different-address-checkbox depending on shipping method is selected.

And finally if shipping is required I scroll the page up to the shipping address.

Remove these features if you don't want them.

```
// When shipping method is selected
    jQuery( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="shipping_method"]', function () {
        var val = jQuery( this ).val();
        if ( val.match( "^local_pickup" ) ) {
            jQuery( '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox' ).prop( "checked", false ); // untick shipping checkbox
            jQuery( '.shipping_address' ).slideUp(); // hide shipping address
        } else {
            jQuery( '.shipping_address' ).slideDown(); // show shipping address
            jQuery( '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox' ).prop( "checked", true ); // tick shipping checkbox
            // scroll to top of shipping address
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(".shipping_address").offset().top - 120
            }, 1500);
        }
    } );
```